# jQuery: How to use the .length property

Tags: jquery

I've been looking around SO and the web in general, and I can't seem to find a simple page where they explain in simple words and simple examples how to us the `.length` method.

What I need help with is quite simple.

I have a drop down menu, and this menu can hold from 1, 2, 3 items to 20 or more.

What I need is a way to detect if there for example, 1 to 10 elements add the class `.one-ten`, and if there are 11 to 20, add the class `.eleven-twenty` instead, and if 21 or more, etc., then add the following class, etc.

I am by no means a jQuery expert, but I've tried doing something like this:

```
$('li').length == 10 $(function());
```

and of course this doesn't work, but it gives you the idea of what I need to accomplish.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `length` is a property not a method.

Comment: are you wanting to style 1-10 different than 11-20 or style them all different depending on how many there are, one of these doesn't even need javascript

Comment: `length` is a property, not a function. Have you looked at the official documentation? http://api.jquery.com/length/ (You may also want to check out [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/))

Comment: What you have attempted doesn't even make sense. It's almost like you're asking us to do it for you.

Comment: @undefined, sorry, I corrected the title, thanks.

Comment: You can't use `()` on a property - it won't deference correctly.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I know it doesn't make any sense, it was only to illustrate what I needed help with. And I already told you that I tried looking around SO and the web and there's nothing out there that's helpful for me. That's why I've asked here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like like below,

```
var $li = $('li');
if ($li.length <= 10) { $li.addClass('one-ten'); }
else if ($li.length <= 20) { $li.addClass('eleven-twenty'); }
```

Comment: You repeated the same condition inside the `else if` condition, fixed that for you. +1 for the objectiveness.

Comment: I usually comment before/instead of fixing, but I'm in my rare edit mood and it would be a shame if such a fast answer wasn't fully functional. `=]`

Comment: @Vega This is *exactly* what I needed to accomplish, a way to structure different amounts and depending on the amounts add a certain class. This is the syntax I was looking for `.length <= 10`. Thanks a lot for your help. Here's a working demo: http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/xgsLv

Answer (score 0):

`.length` is not a method, it's a property. You can determine how many options a select contains using the following code:

```
var numOptions = $('#YourSelectID option').length

if(numOptions < 10) {
    // Code goes here
}
...
```